Is it possible to create a table in Supabase programmatically using the Python client?
I would like to create a table on Supabase programmatically. Is this possible?
Using this code:
from supabase_client import supabase

# SQL statements to create tables
sql_create_tables = """--sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS biomarker (
    name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    unit VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    reference_range_min VARCHAR(100),
    reference_range_max VARCHAR(100),
    description TEXT
);
"""

# Execute raw SQL to create the tables
response = supabase.rpc("execute_sql", {"query": sql_create_tables}).execute()
print(response)

However, I am getting this error when running this code:
postgrest.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 'PGRST202', 'details': 'Searched for the function public.execute_sql with parameter query or with a single unnamed json/jsonb parameter, but no matches were found in the schema cache.', 'hint': None, 'message': 'Could not find the function public.execute_sql(query) in the schema cache'}

Is it just not possible to create a table programmatically on Supabase?

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You might want to look at this. As for your question proper, what happens if you remove the comment --sql?

Thanks for the tip regarding VARCHAR! I removed --sql but I got the same error.

Hmmm... try: from supabase_client import *?

Unrelated, that's just a file of mine in which I initialized Supabase like this: supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)

The only things I can suggest now are a) have you searched through the Supabase source code for execute_sql(query)? Can you even run a simple SELECT with this code? Have you tried on Supabase forums? I don't often recommend off-list here, but this might be a wee bit specialised for this forum?

p.s. if you do receive a good answer, please post it back here and then mark it as correct - this might help others in the future. We may not have answered your particular question this time, but don't be disheartened - these forums are a good resource for PostgreSQL - what with here, the PostgreSQL mailing lists and particular product fora, there's a plethora of help out there! :-)

thanks for your help, will do!
